# Is it possible to loop a 360 degree YouTube video offline?

Tags: video, video-editor, youtube, 360video

I want to put a 360-degree video from YouTube downloaded offline and uploaded to WordPress so the user can immediately view a VR/Google Cardboard split-screen vid (no VPN required). The video would be a continuous loop and act as a "simulation" of an environment. Also, there would be the same capabilities of moving the phone around/gyroscope effect to view the video from a web browser.

Comment: I've added an answer to get you started, but this is really not a production challenge, so I'm voting to close this one. It's rather about coding, I suggest you ask this on stackoverflow or possibly on wordpress.SE or webmasters.SE

Answer (score 1):

You can use [marzipano](http://www.marzipano.net/) which will provide all the code necessary for the viewer and provide you with a Javascript API for customization.

A quick Google search found me [this Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-vr-view/) which claims to do what you want as well.

Honestly, what you're asking is quite complicated. If you can't do it on your own using the tools linked above, I suggest you hire a web developer to do it for you.